# Type error while performing a join in LINQ

Tags: c#

What is wrong in the join condition of the following code snippet?

```
var result = (from p in payments
              join pr in paymentobs on p.PaymentId equals pr.PaymentId 
          Error here --> join ar in accountobs on p.AccountId equals ar.TFLEXID                                
              select new                      
              {
                  PaymentId = ..........,
                  AgencyId = ..........,
                 ..........................
        ..........................
    });
```

The error is

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: Does `p.AccountId` and `ar.TFLEXID` have same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the types of the properties you use in the equals expression doesn't match.

In order to make a join the types on the equals expression should match. That being said, the type of `p.AccountId` should match the type of `ar.TFLEXID`. If this is not true, then you can't make the join as it is.

A possible workaround to this, it would be to convert one member of the equals expression to the the type of the other member, if that's possible at all. This is a workaround provided that doing so makes sense.